# Execute Word Macro from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, call

I am using Excel VBA to run Macros inside of word documents. Essentially I want the code to open all Word documents in a folder (in practice there will be about 180 word documents in this folder), execute the macro "TestFormat", then close the word and move onto the next.

The problem is that it only works for one word file. I can get my excel and my word macros to work independently, but not together. When I run the macro it executes on the first word document in the folder then exits the loop (it displays "Macro is Complete" so it appears that it finishes the excel code, just exited the loop). If I comment out the line " WordApp.Run MacroName:="NewMacros.TestFormat" and debug I can see that it runs through all files in the loop, if I don't comment it out then it only runs through once. Like-wise, I have run the Word macro successfully on all files in the folder if I go into each to execute. Its the combination of the two that doesn't seem to work.

Of note, the word macro does much more than save it as a pdf, it imports csv files and more, but that is working without issue so I didn't include.

Excel Code:

```
Sub WordtoPDF()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim MyFileCSV As String
    Dim FilePathCSV As String
    Dim MyFileWordM As String
    Dim FilePathWordM As String
    Dim MyFilePDF As String
    Dim MyFileWordW As String
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowEnd As Long
    
    

    MsgBox ("Please ensure all word and excel/csv files are closed except for the Macro Manager. Select esc. to exit.")
     
    
    
    MsgBox ("Please select the folder that contains the with code Word files. Select esc. to exit.")
    
    FilePathCSV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(28, 3)
    
    'Identify the folder that the macro files are in
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        FilePathWordM = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(29, 3) = FilePathWordM
    RowEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    'Create Output Folders
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir FilePathWordM & "\Completed Word Output"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir FilePathWordM & "\PDF Output"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(30, 3) = FilePathWordM & "\Completed Word Output"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(31, 3) = FilePathWordM & "\PDF Output"
    

    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
    'Create a Key Excel file with csv file path
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=FilePathWordM & "\Key.xlsx"
    
    'Open first Word document in file
    MyFileWordM = Dir(FilePathWordM & "\*.docm")
      
    Do While MyFileWordM <> ""
        MyFileCSV = Replace(MyFileWordM, ".docm", ".csv")
        FilePathCSV = FilePathCSV & "\" & MyFileCSV
        
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePathCSV
        

        Workbooks("Key").Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = FilePathCSV
        For i = 2 To RowEnd
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Replace(MyFileWordM, ".docm", "") Then
                Workbooks("Key").Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 3)
                i = i + 7000
            End If
        Next i
    
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.DOCUMENTS.Open(FilePathWordM & "\" & MyFileWordM)
        WordApp.Run MacroName:="NewMacros.TestFormat"

        WordApp.activedocument.Close
        'Workbooks.Save Filename:=FilePathCSV
        Workbooks(MyFileCSV).Close Savechanges:=False
  
        'Next file
        FilePathCSV = Replace(FilePathCSV, "\" & MyFileCSV, "")
        MyFileWordM = Dir
    Loop
    
    WordApp.Quit
    
    MsgBox ("Macro is Complete")
    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

**Word Code:**

```
Sub TestFormat()
    ThisDocument.Activate
    
    ThisDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowAll = True
    
    Dim WordDocM As String
    Dim KeyDocM As String
    Dim CSVDoc As String
    Dim CSVPath As String
    Dim FinalWordPath As String
    Dim FinalPDFPath As String

    Dim NewName As String
    
    
    
    WordDocM = ThisDocument.Name
    FinalWordPath = ThisDocument.FullName
    FinalWordPath = Replace(FinalWordPath, WordDocM, "Completed Word Output")
    FinalPDFPath = Replace(FinalWordPath, "Completed Word Output", "PDF Output")
    CSVDoc = Replace(WordDocM, ".docm", ".csv")
    KeyDocM = Replace(ThisDocument.FullName, WordDocM, "key.xlsx")
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set xlBook = xlApp.workbooks.Open(FileName:=KeyDocM)
    CSVPath = xlBook.sheets(1).Range("A1")
    NewName = xlBook.sheets(1).Range("A2")
    
    
    'Put after the other code is executed
    xlBook.Save
    xlBook.Close
    
    ThisDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=FinalWordPath & "\" & NewName & ".docm", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
    
    ThisDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                                       FinalPDFPath & "\" & NewName & ".pdf", _
                                       ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                       OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                       OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                       Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                       IncludeDocProps:=True, _
                                       CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, _
                                       BitmapMissingFonts:=True
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: your `On Error Resume Next` is hiding any potential errors.

Comment: I think it would be better to have the TestFormat function within the same EXCEL workbook (you can add a reference to Word object library), instead of trying to use getobject to report results back to EXCEL. Any reason it needs to be in every Word document?

Comment: FYI `On Error Resume Next` remain in force until you cancel it with (eg) `On Error Goto 0`...

Comment: So the word documents have key identifiers all through them. The code in the word document imports a CSV file with key identifiers and their replacements. This works really well in Word but I haven't been able to get it work successfully calling it in Excel even with using the word object library. That was what I tried first, the code above is my second attempt at getting this process more automated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifier on the On Error Resume Next. I didn't understand that is remained in force.

Comment: Resolved - It was such a simple mistake! I wasn't seeing it because of my on error statement. Thanks for educating me on how to use that. My word code closes the "Key" workbook, so on the second instance of the loop when it references the "Key" workbook I would get a subscript out of range error. I corrected this and now the code works as intended.